# I can use iPad as second display, but I cannot use Universal Control

Tags: macbook-pro, ipad, continuity

As the title says, I cannot use Universal Control with my iPad and mbp (sharing the mbp's mouse/keyboard with the iPad), although the mac sees the iPad (recognizes it, can use it as a secondary display, etc.)

iPad:
6th generation, iOS 15.4

MBP:

- MacBook Pro (16-inch, 2021)
- MacOS Monterey 12.6
- 64 GB
- Universal control enabled under Display settings

Hand off enabled in both devices

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to update the iPad (6th gen) to 15.7

Although Apple lists 15.4 as the min requirement, updating to 15.7 was the only thing that finally worked

Answer (score 0):

According to this guide, Sidecar (extended display) is incompatible with Universal Control. Have you tried turning off Sidecar?

> If you're using ‌Sidecar‌ to mirror or extend your Mac's display to an ‌iPad‌, Universal Control won't work on that iPad and may not work on an additional iPad to Mac, as there are some issues with the way the two features interact during the beta. Turn off Sidecar using the Display panel in your Mac's Control Center to prevent potential issues.

https://www.macrumors.com/guide/universal-control-troubleshooting/